# Mock null object in Junit mockMVC

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockmvc

I am trying to pass null as the content type for JUnit mockMvc but its failing

```
Object obj =null;
MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(post("/mgr/v1/processEvent")
    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    .content(String.valueOf(obj))
    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
    .andDo(print())
    .andExpect(status().is4xxClientError()).andReturn();
```

its not going inside the controller call

Please help

Comment: Next time, please add more information about the way your code is failing (like a stack trace).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `String.valueOf(null);`. Null is interpreted as a char array which leads to a `NullpointerException`. Just use an empty String or leave the complete line.

```
MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(post("/mgr/v1/processEvent")
    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
    .andDo(print())
    .andExpect(status().is4xxClientError()).andReturn();
```